# get selected radio value

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-group

This is the HTML block with radiobuttons:

```
<div id="lokationcontent" class="form-group">
   <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" id="ls0" value="Lokation_Stapelgatan Karlstad">Stapelgatan Karlstad</label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" id="ls1" value="Lokation_Torggatan Karlstad">Torggatan Karlstad</label></div>
   <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" id="ls2" value="Lokation_Värmlandsgatan Karlstad">Värmlandsgatan Karlstad</label></div>
</div>
```

I try to access the selected value with the following jquery code:

```
$('input[name="radioButtonGroup"]:checked').value
```

But the value is undefined when i console.log it, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Jquery objects does not contain a property called `value`. Try,

```
$('input[name="radioButtonGroup"]:checked').val();
```

If you want to use `.value` over this then you have to access the core JS object,

```
$('input[name="radioButtonGroup"]:checked')[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** , the value property does not exist for jQuery objects.

```
$('input[name="radioButtonGroup"]:checked').val()
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2GSS8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use javascript property value to jquery object. You should either convert it to javascript object and use `.value`.like this:

```
$('input[name=radioButtonGroup]:checked')[0].value;
```

Or you need to use jquery method `.val()`:

```
$('input[name=radioButtonGroup]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` is the native JS way of retrieving a value. In jQuery, you need to use `val()`:

```
$('input[name="radioButtonGroup"]:checked').val()
```

If you prefer to use the value property, use:

```
$('input[name="radioButtonGroup"]:checked')[0].value
```